# Cant print result in CMD with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL, I have ran a simple command of Hello world in my command prompt.

```
DECLARE 
message varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!'; 
BEGIN 
dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
/
```

But The hello world did not get displayed in CMD although I am getting the message PL/SQL procedure successfully completed message.
Please help out!

Answer (score 5):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

will help you to print messages from buffer to your CMD...

so try,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE 
message varchar2(20):= 'Hello, World!'; 
BEGIN 
dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
/
```

Comment: @JavaBits - if this answer solved your problem the correct thing to do is to accept it by clicking on the checkbox under the vote total.

Answer (score 0):

use the below sqlplus command to display the output of dbms_output.put_line

```
 set serveroutput on
```

before running the anonymous block

Answer (score 0):

We can write pl/SQL in workspace and execute easy.
Example hello world

```
 Set serveroutput on
     Declare
    message varchar 2(20):='Hello world';
    Begin
   dbms_output.put_line(message);
    End;
    /
```

Result will give
Hello world
Pl/SQL procedure successfully completed .